# To which level Haskell's HDBC is lazy?

Tags: database, haskell

The [HDBC documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-1.1.5/docs/Database-HDBC.html#12) states:

> fetchAllRows :: Statement -> IO [[SqlValue]]Source
>
> Lazily fetch all rows from an executed Statement.
>
> You can think of this as hGetContents applied to a database result
>   set.
>
> The result of this is a lazy list, and each new row will be read,
>   lazily, from the database as the list is processed.
>
> When you have exhausted the list, the Statement will be finished.
>
> Please note that the careless use of this function can lead to some
>   unpleasant behavior. In particular, if you have not consumed the
>   entire list, then attempt to finish or re-execute the statement, and
>   then attempt to consume more elements from the list, the result will
>   almost certainly not be what you want.
>
> But then, similar caveats apply with hGetContents.
>
> Bottom line: this is a very convenient abstraction; use it wisely.
>
> Use fetchAllRows' if you need something that is strict, without all
>   these caveats.

Then, I wonder, to which level does the laziness extend?

Say, I can have

```
  conn <- connectSqlite3 databaseFilePath
  rows <- quickQuery conn ("SELECT * FROM foo") []
  mapM_ bar $ take n rows
  disconnect conn
```

Will it actually only fetch `n` rows? Like, from the database point of view, will it be equivalent of `SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT (n)`? Because fetching all rows at the level of database driver and then `take`ing `n` of them seems to be silly and kind of defeats the purpose.

If it's lazy up to the database itself, how's it implemented? Is it using cursors?

I know there're several drivers for HDBC alone. I'm asking only about principle of implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (though I can't verify) that they're relying on the standard ODBC capability for the data-streaming based on the fact that the documentation says it supports

> [...] and have it work with any number of backend SQL databases (MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, **ODBC-compliant databases**, etc.) [...]

(emphasis mine)

If you'll have a look at MSDNs generic non-DB-specific ODBC API you'll see it has [streaming data reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx) facilities.

Given this, I assume the ODBC standards dictate lazy data streaming facilities, and the HDBC likely just relies on that (possibly with DB-specific heuristics for some particular DB's that may be beneficial beyond what ODBC supplies).